# Spring @Requestbody not mapping to inner class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am doing Spring Rest Api project with Spring 4.x

**This Works:**

*Controller.java*

```
@PostMapping("newTransaction")
TransactionRequestModel insertNewTransaction(@RequestBody TransactionRequestModel model){
    //do something
}
```

*TransactionRequestModel.java*

```
public class TransactionRequestModel {
    private int id;
    private List<KeyValue> keyValueList;
    public TransactionRequestModel(){}
    //default constructor
    //getter-setter 
}
```

*KeyValue.java*

```
public class KeyValue {

    String key;
    String value;
    //default constructor
    //setter-getter
}
```

*Request Body Json*

```
{
  "id": 1 
  "keyValueList": [
    {
      "key": "dummy",
      "value": "dummy"
    }
  ]
}
```

Spring message converter using jackson is working fine.

**This Won't:**

When i change *TransactionRequestModel.java* to following (and delete *KeyValue.java*)

```
public class TransactionRequestModel {

    public class KeyValue {     
      String key;
      String value;
      //default constructor
      //setter-getter
    }
    private int id;
    private List<KeyValue> keyValueList;
    public TransactionRequestModel(){}
    //default constructor
    //getter-setter 
}
```

means, making *KeyValue* an **inner class**, got following error.

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read document: No suitable constructor found for type
>   [simple type, class
>   com.example.model.TransactionRequestModel$KeyValue]: can not
>   instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator,
>   or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)

**Why?**

All the related post in SO mentions the first scenario. I would like to know why this wont work. Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to make your inner class `static`.

```
public class TransactionRequestModel {

  public static class KeyValue {     
    String key;
    String value;
    //default constructor
    //setter-getter
  }
  private int id;
  private List<KeyValue> keyValueList;
  public TransactionRequestModel(){}
  //default constructor
  //getter-setter 
}
```

Comment: You may refer to this answer for a good explanation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class