# How to bind an array field in java spring framwork?

Tags: java, json, spring

Hi these is my model that inclues some simple field and a set of OrderModel.

```
public class ActiveRequsetModel {
 private Long id;
 private String applicatorDescription;
 private Customer customer;
 private Set<OrderModel> odersModel = new HashSet<>();
}
```

and this is my method in my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register-request", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> registerActiveRequest(@RequestBody ActiveRequsetModel activeRequsetModel){

        customerService.registerActiveRequest(activeRequsetModel);

        return new ResponseEntity<>("Request registered.", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

and this is what I get from client side as you see it includes a applicatorDescription, customer object and a List of orderModel with key ordersModel.

```
{
    "applicatorDescription" : "quick please",
    "customer" : {
       "id" : 1
    },
"ordersModel" : 
[
    {
        "transfereeName" : "Alex",
        "address" : "home",
        "countOrSize" : 12.5,
        "derap" : 4,
        "description" : "descriptionnnnn",
        "kalite" : {
            "id" : 1
        },
        "product" : {
            "id" : 1
        }
    }
]
```

}

When I get request spring can bind customer and applicatorDescription, but It can't bind ordersModel.
What should I do?

Comment: Make sure you don't make spelling mistakes: ActiveRequsetModel -> ActiveRequestModel, oderModel -> ordersModel

Answer (score 0):

Your Model class is here:

```
public class ActiveRequsetModel {
 private Long id;
 private String applicatorDescription;
 private Customer customer;
 private Set<OrderModel> oderModel = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Change `private Set<OrderModel> oderModel = new HashSet<>();` as

```
private List<OrderModel> oderModel
```

**Also, `OrderModel` class should independent class. If `OrderModel` is an inner class then jacson cannot bind the request with class.**

For more info visit [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51414623/3073945)

Hope this will help you